# Error while Adding expect library (https://github.com/mjackson/expect) in JSBin.com

Tags: ecmascript-6, jsbin

While trying to add Expect library in Jsbin.com console, it return undefined.

```
var mylib = {
  text: 'My Category',
  scripts: [
    { text: 'My library', url: 'https://github.com/mjackson/expect/blob/master/modules/index.js' }
  ]
};
libraries.add(mylib);
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you add script tag in the head. Try this in jsbin.com

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/expect@%3C21/umd/expect.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    console.log("expect", expect.createSpy)
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this stand alone module:

```
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/expect@22.4.3"></script>
```

put it in your `head` tag of the HTML file.